# How can I completely reinstall gnome-control-center and reset default settings?

Tags: gnome-control-center

I'm quite new to Linux so I please bear with me.

The problem I'm having is that I have accidentally removed a system setting panel from **gnome-control-center**, using the **Main Menu** app. I thought it would remove the icon from my applications, but it seems to have removed the entire panel from system settings, making it impossible for me to get in to the settings again.

My question is, is it possible to completely remove gnome-control-center, refresh all the defaults, then re-install it again in hopes of bringing the panels back?

I get these errors in my terminal when trying to run gnome-control-center:

```
** (gnome-control-center:4523): WARNING **: 17:55:15.125: Ignoring broken panel wifi (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:4523): WARNING **: 17:55:15.126: Ignoring broken panel wacom (missing desktop file)
**
ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:419:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
Bail out! ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:419:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Those are the panels I accidentally removed.

Yes, I know it was dumb to remove them, but please, I've only JUST migrated to Linux and learning as I go along.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the package should bring back the files you deleted

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center --reinstall
```